# Am getting 404 error for style.cs and config.js and main.js file when trying to run angularjs2 application

Tags: angular

[image: **enter image description here**]

When am trying to run angular2 application am getting the following error The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). for the style.css,config.js,main.js files am not sure why this is happening When I commented the style.css and config.js the errors were not their but I need those file
 Thanks in advance

This is the error I got When I run the app in IE

[image: This is the error I got When I run the app in IE]

Comment: How do you run the app? ng serve??

Comment: using the command prompt npm start

Comment: using the lite server  in command prompt (npm start command)

Comment: I guess you need to map your files in system.config.js instead of directly referencing them.

Comment: Have you had faced similar issue before and mapping files in system.config you mean I need to refer them in system.config.js files